# TULEAP - LDAP Plugin & Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, tuleap

I ve installed Tuleap 7.2 on CentOS and activate the Ldap plugin to auth against an AD running Samba 4.1.9.

For the moment I have no success trying to connect to my AD.

Here is my ldap.inc :

```
$sys_ldap_server = "192.168.x.x";
$sys_ldap_dn     = "dc=xx,dc=corp";
$sys_ldap_bind_dn = "cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=xx,dc=corp";
$sys_ldap_bind_passwd = "password;
$sys_ldap_uid   = "sAMAccountName";
$sys_ldap_eduid = "sAMAccountName";
$sys_ldap_cn    = "cn";
$sys_ldap_mail  = "mail";
$sys_ldap_people_dn     = "cn=users,dc=xx,dc=corp";
$sys_ldap_search_user="(|(uid=%words%)(cn=%words%)(mail=%words%))";

.....
```

Iptable is correctly configure and 389 port reachable, but when i try to login from tuleap 
it's a NO GO.

"Invalid Password Or User Name"

If you have an idea I'll take it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should try with ldap_search on the Tuleap host

Something like:

ldap_search -x -h 192.168.x.x -LLL -D cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=xx,dc=corp -W -b dc=xx,dc=corp "sAMAccountName=yourlogin"

and see if it returns anything (that's basically what's Tuleap is doing when you try to login)